# R Markdown is not rendering Table of Contents or Tabsets

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown, tableofcontents

Trying to format an html document in R markdown with a table of contents and tabsets under certain headers. Using the cheatsheet, a book, and online sources, I think it should be set correctly. However it seems to not render correctly

I have tried to do one at a time and neither works. I have even copied code exactly and rendered and it doesn't show up the same.

I have reinstalled knitr and rmarkdown packages to no avail.

I am running R 5.35.1

````
---
title: Water Conditions and Operations
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: true
      smooth_scroll: true 
---


```{r}
```

## Kings River   

<center>
Insert Image
</center>


### Pine Flat {.tabset}    



#### Daily  

hi  

#### Weekly  

hi  

#### Monthly  

hi  

### Upstream {.tabset}  

#### Daily

#### Weekly

#### Monthly

## State Water Project 

### Precipitation

### Snow

```{r}

```


[Kings River]
````

I expect there to be a tabset like on how I did on a shiny app. But these just appear as normal headers

Comment: just gave it a try and get [this](http://jamesbrusey.coventry.domains/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Screen-Shot-2019-07-03-at-19.04.26.png) with R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23), and most recent knitr / rmarkdown on macosx Rstudio Version 1.1.447

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying it out. Mine just renders plainly. No table of contents, no tabsets or anything. I have updated R and all the packages. Could you point me where to look next?

Comment: First thing: is it pandoc or your browser? The one I rendered with is [here](http://jamesbrusey.coventry.domains/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/x.html) and if this still doesn't look right, the problem is with your browser. Otherwise, I'm guessing it's something in pandoc. In that case, reduce your code to the smallest thing that reproduces the problem (e.g., two headings, one with .tabset) and then experiment with pandoc from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem:

- Uninstalled R
- Uninstalled R Studio
- Deleted all Program File Directories for these programs
- Installed the newest version of R and R Studio

Knitted to html and it worked